# How do I resolve MySQL Error 1111 in the SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, where-clause, clause

I'm executing an SQL statement below in Workbench

```
select count(1) as NoOfMovies, rating from film 
where rating <> 'G' 
group by rating 
having count(NoOfMovies) > 200;
```

But I'm getting an error here.

`ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

The statement looks good and I'm unable to understand what is causing this error. Clauses are also in order.

Thanks,
Piyush.

Comment: It will be `having NoOfMovies > 200`  you don't need to count again.

Comment: You type `having count(NoOfMovies) > 200`. But `NoOfMovies` is `count(1) as NoOfMovies`, so you type `having count(count(1)) > 200`. of course MySQL doesn't like this..